# Load and Show Excel File Contents as HTML Table Angular with XLSX

Tags: javascript, angular, excel, typescript, xlsx

**What I want:**

I'm trying to load an excel file and display its contents as an HTML element. Apparently, everything is ok (console logs prints correct data).

**The problem**

Excel content is not shown at HTML **until you upload twice** the file!!

**Some clues**

Using this example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-excel-read-table?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsheet.component.ts

Excel contents loads second time code pass throw: `reader.readAsBinaryString(changeEvent.target.files[0]);`

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

type AOA = any[][];

  data: AOA = [
    ['default']
  ];

  onFileChange(changeEvent: any) {

    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = () => {

      const wb = XLSX.read(reader.result, { type: 'binary' });
      
      const firstSheetName = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const firstSheetWBook = wb.Sheets[firstSheetName];

      this.data = <AOA>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(firstSheetWBook, { header: 1 }));
      console.log(this.data) // prints correct data at console
    };

    reader.readAsBinaryString(changeEvent.target.files[0]);

  }
```

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" multiple="false">
<span>{{ data }}</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because `reader.onload` is "outside of Angular's world" so Angular doesn't pick up the change.

The workaround to force Angular to refresh and pick up the changes is to use `NgZone`. Try this :

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
    
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) { }
```

```
console.log(this.data) // prints correct data at console
this.ngZone.run(() => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `readAsArrayBuffer` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString) states:

> Note that this method was once removed from the File API specification, but re-introduced for backward compatibility.
> Using FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer() is recommended.

However, the FileReader is also discouraged, since you can just as well use the new read methods on the [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) instead. NodeJS v15.7 comes with blobs built in, but dose not have a FileReader cuz it's consider as a legacy api now that there is new read methods

Example below:

```js
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

async function onFileChange (evt) {
  const buffer = await evt.target.files[0].arrayBuffer()
  const wb = XLSX.read(buffer);
  
  const firstSheetName = wb.SheetNames[0];
  const firstSheetWBook = wb.Sheets[firstSheetName];

  this.data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(firstSheetWBook, { header: 1 });
  console.log(this.data) // prints correct data at console
}
```